# Why isn't dplyr::filter() working with elements of a vector?

Tags: mysql, r, filter, timestamp, dbplyr

I have some data in a MySQL database that I'm filter and pulling into R studio to work with. I've come across a weird problem where I can't use elements of a vector with time stamps to filter the data. However, the filter function does work if I hardcode the time stamp of interest or assign the value to a variable first.

Can anyone else reproduce and/or explain this behavior?

The data below will also have a vector of end times and I'd like to filter the data by the intervals defined in the start and end times without using tons of or statements if anyone has a good way to do that.

```
# vector with times of interest for filtering
  start.times <- as.POSIXct(c("2021-06-10 15:30:00", "2021-06-17 12:50:00", "2021-06-18 14:12:00"), tz = "UTC")
```

```
# dbconn is a connection to a MySQL database
# table is the name of the first table in the database
# the first column of the table is named time and contains an SQL timestamp in UTC
table <- dbListTables(dbconn)[1]
data.to.filter <- tbl(dbconn,  table) # want to filter this based on time column

# this does not work. It returns Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s) [1241]
filter(data.to.filter, time > (start.times[1]))

# This does work
start.time1 = start.times[1]
filter(data.to.filter, time > (start.time1))

# This also works
filter(data.to.filter, time > ("2021-06-10 15:30:00"))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because of how dbplyr translates R code to SQL code. When you call

```r
filter(data.to.filter, time > (start.times[1]))
```

The translator will likely identify the transformation `time > (start.times[1])` and determine how to translate it. If it translates to SQL before interpreting the contents, then it will translate `start.times[1]` rather than evaluating it.

You could test this using `show_query`:

```r
filter(data.to.filter, time > (start.times[1])) %>% show_query()
```

I would expect you to see `[1]` turn up in the generated SQL. This would confirm that translation is occurring before evaluation.

If you want to force evaluation before translation, then I suspect you can accomplish this via `enquo` or `eval`. I recommend you take a look at [Advanced R, Evaluation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/evaluation.html).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm confirming the generated SQL is different. I wasn't able to get either 'eval' or 'enquo' to work. I'll have to do some digging in the reference you sent.

' filter(data.to.filter, time > time1) %>% show_query()'  

<SQL>  

SELECT *  

FROM `tablenamehidden`  

WHERE (`time` > '2021-06-10T15:30:00Z')  

'filter(data.to.filter, time > times[1]) %>% show_query()'  

<SQL>  

SELECT *  

FROM `tablenamehidden`<br/>

WHERE (`time` > CASE WHEN (1.0) THEN (('2021-06-10T15:30:00Z', '2021-06-17T12:50:00Z', '2021-06-18T14:12:00Z')) END)'